# If URL contains string x then run something

Tags: php

I would like to check the url to see if it contains a certain value. If yes run the code. Below is how my url would look like.

```
www.url.com/test/stats.php?player=neo
www.url.com/test/stats.php?player=morpheus
www.url.com/test/stats.php?player=anderson

$userName = $_GET['player'];
```

I would like to do something like

```
if ( urlheader contains $userName ) {
    //run some code
}
```

Comment: `if ($userName == "neo") { echo "Hello Neo!"; }`

Comment: `Contains` is more about `strpos` than simple `==`, I think

Comment: @Dan your link was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this. However it won't work with `$_POST`

```
if($_GET['player']){
    $username = $_GET['player']
    //Do your stuff with $username here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
$userName = $_GET['player'];
if (strpos($url,$userName) !== false) {
    //your scripts
}
```

or

```
$userName = $_GET['player'];
if($userName == 'Your checking value')
{
    //your scripts
}
```